# A riddle that is dear to me

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> I am but a basic, simple thing,
> But joy to the hearts of many I do bring.
> I am made up of four, without them I'm not,
> If you name them first, then me you will spot.
>
> To my first, you may not give a thought
> But without it, all life would come to naught.
> It's in you, it's around you, it's easy to see
> It may seem quite boring, but it's vital to me.
>
> My second does begin so grassy and green,
> But then, when gold hair starts to be seen -
> It's time for a bath to trigger new life
> Then crank up the heat 'til sweetness is rife.
>
> My third is a lady, old and bitter.
> She wears perfume though, she's no quitter.
> Sometimes she's abundant, sometimes she's rare,
> Just as long as she's there, though, I don't care.
>
> My last has a sweet tooth, impossible to quench,
> He can get quite gassy, and produce such a stench!
> He eats all he can, a bit like a vulture,
> Still I keep him around, for at least he has culture.
>
> Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you by any chance:

> BEER

The first part being

> WATER which may be boring but is essential to life

The second part being:

> WHEAT or I guess any other grain you like which grows from green until it is gold and harvested.

The third being:

> HOPS which are definitely bitter and used in differing strengths

The last being:

> YEAST which eats sugar and produces gas... also "Culture" haha! :P

Comment: Nice work, exactly right!